# Can't create my database using doctrine-module cli command

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a problem with [doctrine-module](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) console using zend framework 2 and postgresql

```
ricardo@notebook:/var/www/zendskeleton$ bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
PHP Warning:  array_map(): An error occurred while invoking the map callback in /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src/DoctrineORMModule/Module.php on line 138

Warning: array_map(): An error occurred while invoking the map callback in /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src/DoctrineORMModule/Module.php on line 138
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "zend" does not exist' in /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'morphy09', Array)
#1 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOPgSql/Driver.php(46): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#2 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver->connect(Array, 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#3 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
#4 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion()
#5 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/li in /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 930

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "zend" does not exist' in /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#1 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOPgSql/Driver.php(46): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#2 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver->connect(Array, 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#3 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
#4 /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion()
#5 /var/www/utilcore/vendor/doctrine/dbal/li in /var/www/zendskeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 930
```

I have a doctrine.local.php config file:

```
<?php

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver',
                'params' => [
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '5432',
                    'user'     => 'postgres',
                    'password' => 'postgres',
                    'dbname'   => 'zend',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Basically, I cant create my database using doctrine-module cli command.

Why i'm getting this error?

If I create the database using psql all the doctrine-module commands works very well, but the doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create is there for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because doctrine tries to create your tables in a a database called `zend` and this database doesn't exist. You should check your database setup and see if there is a database available with the name `zend`.

Comment: But the command 'bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create' shouldn't create the database for me?

Comment: @RicardoSimas : The [create-scheme](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation) command will create the database scheme in the given database. "It will drop or alter tables, indexes, sequences and such", so it won't create the database.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what is happened here.